# Having trouble implementing pagination into my code using axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

I am a beginner to REACT and I am trying to figure out how to implement pagination into my React project using axios. The api I am using (swapi.dev) has a total of 87 characters, when you submit a GET request with https://swapi.dev/api/people you only get 10 characters per page, but to can use the link in postman, which says "next" to switch between each pages of characters. I am trying to make an request with axios to paginate each list of 10. I figured a for loop would be good to use but I am not sure.

```html
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import _ from "lodash";
import ReactPaginate from "react-paginate";
import Table from "react-bootstrap/Table";

export default function Posts() {
  const [characterData, setCharacterData] = useState([]);

  //use a for loop to loop through all sites
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://swapi.dev/api/people/")
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data.next);
        setCharacterData(res.data.results);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);

  // for ( i = 0; i < data.results.length, i++) {
  //   names = names + data.results[i].name
  // }

  // function handleclick(e) => {

  // }

  return (
    <>
      <Table stripped bordered hover className="project--table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Birth Year</th>
            <th>Height</th>
            <th>Mass</th>
            <th>Homeworld</th>
            <th>Species</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {characterData.map((character, index) => {
            return (
              <tr key={index}>
                <td>{character.name}</td>
                <td>{character.birth_year}</td>
                <td>{character.height}</td>
                <td>{character.mass}</td>
                <td>{character.homeworld}</td>
                <td>{character.species}</td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
      {/* <button onClick={}>Next</button> */}
    </>
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your api and the next key have a value that contains the url for the next page. No need for a loop you can just check if the next key exists and depending on that you send a request.
you can create a new state that will contain the next uri and on the onClick function you check if for the "next" key.
it's something like this :

```
const [next,setNext]= useState("");
```

in the useEffect you wrote you can add :

```
axios
      .get("https://swapi.dev/api/people/")
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data.next);
        setCharacterData(res.data.results);
        if (res.data.next) setNext(res.data.next);


      })
```

and finally in the onClick function :

```
if(next) {
axios.get(next).then(res=> setCharacterData(res.data.results))
}
```

I think there is a better solution for this but you can work with this atm.